# Android Spinner variant header/content width

Tags: android, spinner

I have a requirement that I need to satisfy with regards to android spinner. I need to have a spinner in which the header content is much smaller in width then the content row's width. At the moment the header automatically changes to be the exact same width as the content.

Is it possible to have a header which is smaller and the drop down content is bigger. Also the header should be centered. I have drawn a rudimentary ascii diagram of the intended effect that I wish to achieve. Any help on this matter would be highly appreciated.

```
             |----------------|
             | header content |
             |----------------|
  -----------------------------------------
 | spinner content row text that is bigger |
 -------------------------------------------
 | more spinner content                    |
 -------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the setDropDownWidth in spinner xml

```
<Spinner
    setDropDownWidth='x'
    ....
/>
```

Comment: The control is created programmatically. However I will try that no problem! However I have a quick question before I do. As the name suggests this is meant for the Drop Down, not the header. How does this help with ensuring that header content is truly wrap content and so is the drop down list as the ascii art suggests.